# decimal error in std::strtod() with Visual Studio 2015, 64 bit

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, std, 32bit-64bit, strtod

`std::strod()` converts string to double. But in one particular case, there is a tiny decimal error. This error can also be seen with `atof()` and `sscanf()`. The error only occurs if **all** the following conditions are met:

- Visual Studio 2015 (or VS 2015 update 1)
- Build for 64 bit (x64)
- Call to `_controlfp_s()` to set "rounding towards minus infinity"
- The number has a decimal part, e.g. 0.5 or 2.5 (not an integer)

(I have only tested on 64 bit Windows 8.1 Enterprise)
A simple example is here:

```
#include <string>

inline double fromString(const std::string& s) {
   size_t idx;
   return std::stod(s, &idx);
}

int main()
{
   double res1 = fromString("0.5");
   unsigned tmp;
   _controlfp_s(&tmp, RC_DOWN, MCW_RC);
   double res2 = fromString("0.5");
   _controlfp_s(&tmp, RC_NEAR, MCW_RC);
   double res3 = fromString("0.5");
}
```

`std::stod()` is calling `std::calling strtod()` in stdlib.h.
`res1` will be exactly 0.5, but `res2` will be 0.50000000000000011

`_controlfp_s(&tmp, RC_DOWN, MCW_RC);` controls rounding errors, in this case it is set to round towards minus infinity.
If it is set back to default with `_controlfp_s(&tmp, RC_NEAR, MCW_RC);` then `strod()` is exact again, so `res3` is 0.5

Note that some decimal numbers cannot be represented exactly. But some numbers can, e.g. 2.5, 0.5, and 0.375, but they all get a rounding error in the above example.

Weird, isn't it?

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in Visual Studio's standard library?

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: You have got 15 correct decimals, which is the maximum you can expect from a `double`.

Comment: When you start messing around with FPU control word, all bets concerning standard library functions are off.  Hard to call it a "bug", you're simply operating outside the design.

Comment: Almost every version of strtod has some bugs.  Here are some examples for VC++2015:  http://www.exploringbinary.com/visual-c-plus-plus-strtod-still-broken/

Comment: @BenVoigt: Does Microsoft state somewhere that they do not support change og FPU control word? Or is it just your expectation?

Comment: @BenVoigt: At [The Visual C++ Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/06/18/crt-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-visual-studio-14-ctp1.aspx) they state that "The FLT_ROUNDS macro is now dynamic and correctly reflects the current rounding mode". To me, that indicates that MS at least has the good intention of handling this correctly.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: Thank you for the link. Very useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the link from Adrian McCarthy, I found a work-around: To use 
`fesetround()` instead of `_controlfp_s()`:

```
#if _MSC_VER == 1900
   //Visual Studio 2015
   fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD);
#else
   _controlfp_s(&tmp, RC_DOWN, MCW_RC);
#endif
```

`fesetround()` was introduced in VS2015.
I will report the bug to Microsoft.
One could also use `#if _MSC_VER == 1900 && defined(_WIN64)` to be more precise, since the bug is not there for 32 bit targets.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug. It's a feature!

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Hi Gianluca, Loke Astari already posted that link. Could you be a bit more specific, why you think this bug is a feature?